# What is the idea of using groups in Bean Validation

Tags: java, bean-validation

What is the idea of using groups in short?
For example, the class definition has no groups now. What's going to change if we enable groups below?

```
//  @Size(min = 4, max = 30, groups = LengthGroup.class)
    @Size(min = 4, max = 30)
    private String name;

//  @Size(min = 12, max = 120, groups = LengthGroup.class)
    @Size(min = 12, max = 120)
    private String address;

//  @Size(min = 5, max = 30, groups = LengthGroup.class)
    @Size(min = 5, max = 30)
    @EmailAddress//(groups = EmailGroup.class)
    private String email;
```

p.s. there are also two corresponding interfaces for those groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often useful to declare the same constraint more than once to the same target, with different properties. That's what the group is about. Consider this example:

```
public class Address {
    @ZipCode.List( {
            @ZipCode(countryCode="fr", groups=Default.class
                     message = "zip code is not valid"),
            @ZipCode(countryCode="fr", groups=SuperUser.class
                     message = "zip code invalid. Requires overriding before saving.")
            } )
    private String zipcode;
}
```

In this example, both constraints apply to the zipcode field but with different groups and with different error messages.

Example taken from [here](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/).

Answer (score 1):

In addition what kocko said, they are also meant to categorize validation rules. Quoting from the [JSR-303 final spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr303/index.html):

> Groups allow you to restrict the set of constraints applied during validation.

If you re-add the groups mentioned above and call the validatior like this: `validator.validate(user, LengthGroup.class);`, the lengths of your fields only will be validated. This means that the `@EmailAddress` constraint is not taken into consideration.

If you call the validator like this: `validator.validate(user, LengthGroup.class, EmailGroup.class);`, all your constraints will be validated against.

A use-case more intended for this feature would be validation a version of the user with contact data, and one without. Consider the folling example:

```
@Size(min = 4, max = 30)
private String name;

@Size(min = 12, max = 120, groups=WithContactInfo.class)
private String address;

@Size(min = 5, max = 30, groups= WithContactInfo.class)
@EmailAddress(groups = WithContactInfo.class)
private String email;
```

Now you could validate a user that does not need to have contact info with `validator.validate(user)`, and a user that needs to have contact info too with `validator.validate(user, WithContactInfo.class)`.